# Splitting principle in algebraic geometry and ample line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, line-bundles

Splitting theorem in algebraic geometry claims that if we have a vector bundle $V$ on $X$ (we consider a smooth projective variety for this question), if we pull-back $V$ to $\mathbb{P}(V)$, we get a sub-line bundle of the pulled back vector bundle. Repeating this pull-back procedure we will have a filtration of sub-bundles $V_0\subseteq V_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq V_n=V $ such that $L_i=V_{i+1}/V_{i}$, is a line bundle. Is there a way that we do a splitting similar to this but with some more control on $L_i$'s? I'm particularly interested whether it is possible to find $L_i$'s such that for any two $L_i$ and $L_j$, if $L_i\ncong L_j$, then either one of $L_i\otimes L_j^{-1}$ or  $L_j\otimes L_i^{-1}$ is an ample line bundle. (We can replace ampleness with weaker conditions like big and nef and ask the similar question.)

Edit: In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0354.pdf) paper, end of lemma 7.6, it is claimed that the regular splitting procedure for a point with a trivial vector bundle on it, satisfy the property above. More precisely, if we pull-back it to $\text{Flag}(V)$, the $L_i$'s that we get satisfy the property, $L_i\otimes L_j^{-1}$ is ample for $i>j$. Although I do not understand the given reference at this point, I wonder whether just the regular splitting in general does satisfy this property or not?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a variety $Y$ that can replace $\mathbb{P}(V)$ in the statement of the splitting principle (which has the additional property that there is a way to filter pullbacks so that your condition on the quotients holds) or are you asking if there is a different short exact sequence on $\mathbb{P}(V)$ (i.e.\ not the Euler exact sequence) that gives you such a filtration with the given property?

Comment: The variety $Y$, doesn't need to be the same $\mathbb{P}(V)$.  I want some pullback that is injective on rational algebraic $K$-theory, which for $\mathbb{P}(V)$ it is.  Some of these types of pullbacks include finite etale covers and Frobenius (in the positive char case).

Comment: Another example of good morphism could be a blow-up morphism. But everything in blow-up needs to be smooth. The variety $X$, the closed sub-variety $Z$,  the blow-up along $Z$, and the exceptional divisor.